# Setting Linq to SQL Type Names in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2010, linq-to-sql

I love Linq but it can rapidly clutter up the namespace with automatically generated types. Usually these automatically generated types are often irritatingly close to other objects leading to many hours of fun and laughter.

In the designer I notice that I can specify the table names, however I can not for the life of me see how to set the row names.

For Example
TableName : User_Table
RowName   : User_Row  as opposed to "User_Tables"

I swear I've done this before but I can't seem to remember how.

Comment: I'm not sure that you can control this through the designer.  You normally set the data class name as a singular ("Customer") and it automatically pluralizes the table name ("Customers") for you.  Are you using the designer (or SqlMetal) or writing the entities yourself?

Comment: I am using the designer for this currently. I'll have to take a look at how to do it manually.

Comment: It's normally an all-or-nothing proposition... but the `DataContext` is a partial class, so if you wanted to, you could extend it with a `Table<User>` property and hand-code only the `User` class, or use `SqlMetal` for that one entity and rename it.  Seems like a lot of effort though, why not just call it `User` and let the table name be `Users`?

Comment: This may be one of my many irrational coding quirks but I tend to like to isolate my data context and related classes from the rest of my code. For example this datacontext is internal to my Auth assembly. It has its own User class that is exposed and used by my code behind pages.

Comment: Eek.  Put the dbml in a separate namespace maybe?  Or, if you're not going to change it that often, maybe use SqlMetal instead of the designer and just rename the property and/or entity class.  Sorry, that's all I got!

Comment: Cool - I will definitely check SqlMetal out in the morning. Thank you very much for your help! Yeah this is one of those things that isn't really essential but is driving me to distraction. I'm usually ok at work - but on personal projects I get really insane about these things. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by manually editing the dbml file in an xml editor. All names are stored separately in the dbml file, but not all are accessible from the designer.

Alternatively, there are third party tools that make handling names etc easier; one such tool is my VS add-in for L2S and EF. It adds naming rule support, mass-renaming, model <-> db schema sync etc to the existing L2S designer. You can download it from http://www.huagati.com/dbmltools/